# Workflows in Blender

Tags: workflow, scene, asset-browser

I'm a Blender noobie and am trying to understand project organization in Blender - what the tool provides and best practices. I'm trying to storyboard a short film and was wondering how to organize it.

I understand that I'm building models to construct scenes as well as rigging characters. Say I build a collection of assets (a lamp for a room, a table for a room, etc.). How does organizing a scene work, like say if you are going to reuse a set for multiple scenes? If you build a set/location where you are expecting the scene to occur, is that just an asset composed of assets that you reimport into another scene? Is the scene where animation is laid out, or is that somewhere else?

I assume that this question is a duplicate of something someone else has asked, but receiving links to places these questions are answered is probably what I need at this point.

Comment: Question: Have you studied using the asset library?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure of how much of a use this can be to you, if you are storyboarding?

Anyway, the common pipeline is pretty much how you described:

- assets are made individually
- scenes are build with instances of said assets
- downstream use these scenes as they are, when relevant to their work.

Now to be honest, each studio or even production within the same studio can make somewhat their own pipeline that fits their needs.

Last time I worked on a movie, the scenes were built once, with each shots' camera, and previz anim, all in one file per sequence. Then, for each shot, they exported the relevant part of the scene to a different file, which is what the animators would import in their own software to animate on.

Most of the time, each department pull only the data they need to be able to work, and pushes only the data they made into the pipeline. Animators pull only the rigged characters, camera, audio track and parts of the scenes model that are needed to animate (like the ground for feet contacts, props interacted with the character, and the rest of the scene is often either left out, or imported only as a GPU cache for performance, or imported as a background image sequence) and push only raw animation data, texture artists only pull models and push textures, and so on.

Comment: Maybe what I meant was, "I'm in the planning stages and looking for how to organize a short film." Thanks! This answers what I was asking.

Comment: Each production pipeline is different, and (team) size matters. A lot of procedures are to avoid losing work, people stepping on each other's toes or different ppl redoing the same job. Whenever you think about how to do stuff, basically keep in mind that you want it to be efficient and foolproof.

Answer (score 1):

If a project grows in size and team members, you should get familiar with "Append, Link and Library Overrides".

Append is the standard method to import an asset or a serie of assets from a .blend file to another. Every datablock generated by the software can be reused in another .blend file, the safest way to import is to prepare everything you need into a collection and then append the whole collection, that can contain from a single little prop to a big and complex scene.

Link is similar to Append, except that every time the assets are loaded they get read from the original source .blend file, so that if an asset is shared by 20 different .blend files and it gets modified in its source file, all 20 file users get automatically updated.

Library overrides let you introduce variations on linked assets, so that you can have multiple different instances that all refer to a single source file.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/linked_libraries/link_append.html